# Problem with tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I want to achieve **One** table like this [image]

I've already tried to do only **One Table** but I failed, so I start doing each table alone like this  [image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article} 
\usepackage[paperheight=12in,paperwidth=8.75in ,left=0.2in,right=0.2in,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{rgb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{logo}} \\\hline
\end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
 \textbf{{\Large Examen National 2011 Normale } }\\
 Sciences Experimentales et ses filières \\
 Sciences Technologies Industrielles et ses filières \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{| l |}
\hline
Matière : Mathématiques \\
\hline
Durée de l'épreuve : 3h \\
\hline
Coefficient : 7  \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
Page \\
\cline{1-1}
\diagbox[dir=SW]{1}{2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\

\begin{tabular}{| c | l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ }&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ }\\[-0.6cm]
 & {\centering \colorbox{lightgray}{{\textcolor{ferrarired}{\textbf{{\large Exercice 1 } }} ( $2.5$ points )} }} \\ [0.2cm]
&\bf{On considère la suite numérique $(u_{n})$ définie par :} \\ & $\displaystyle{u_{0}=2}$ et $\displaystyle{u_{n+1}=\frac{3+u_{n}}{5-u_{n}}}$ \bf{pour tout entier naturel $n$.}\\ [0.2cm]
 0.75 & \textcolor{ao}{\large 1)} \bf{Vérifier que $\displaystyle{u_{n+1}-3=\frac{4(u_{n}-3)}{2+(3-u_{n})}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$} \\
& \bf{puis montrer par récurrence que $\displaystyle{u_{n}< 3}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.}\\ [0.2cm]
& \textcolor{ao}{\large 2)} \bf{Soit $(v_{n})$ la suite numérique telle que :  $v_{n}=\displaystyle{\frac{u_{n}-1}{3-u_{n}}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.} \\[0.2cm]
0.75 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large a.} \bf{Montrer que $(v_{n})
$ est une suite géométrique de raison $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}$}\\ 
& \hspace{.3in} \bf{puis en déduire que $v_{n}=\displaystyle{\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.}  \\ [0.2cm] 
0.5 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large b.} \bf{Montrer que $u_{n}=\displaystyle{\frac{1+3v_{n}}{1+v_{n}}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$ puis écrire $u_{n}$ en fonction de $n$.}\\[0.2cm] 
0.5 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large c.} \bf{Déterminer la limite de la suite $\left(u_n\right)$.} \\[0.3cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely still in need of improvement and with quite a number of manual adjustments, but probably nevertheless a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article} 
\usepackage[paperheight=12in,paperwidth=8.75in ,left=0.2in,right=0.2in,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{rgb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}l@{}|X|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} 
& \makecell{\textbf{{\Large Examen National 2011 Normale } }\\
            Sciences Experimentales et ses filières \\
            Sciences Technologies Industrielles et ses filières}
& \begin{tabular}{l} Matière : Mathématiques \\ \hline
                     Durée de l'épreuve : 3h \\ \hline
                     Coefficient : 7  \\ 
   \end{tabular} 
&  \begin{tabular}{c} Page \\[6pt] \hline
                      \diagbox[dir=SW]{1}{2}\\
\end{tabular} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{-1pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | X |}
\hline
&\\[-0.6cm]
 & {\centering \colorbox{lightgray}{{\textcolor{ferrarired}{\textbf{{\large Exercice 1 } }} ( $2.5$ points )} }} \\ [0.2cm]
&\bf{On considère la suite numérique $(u_{n})$ définie par :} \\ & $\displaystyle{u_{0}=2}$ et $\displaystyle{u_{n+1}=\frac{3+u_{n}}{5-u_{n}}}$ \bf{pour tout entier naturel $n$.}\\ [0.2cm]
 0.75 & \textcolor{ao}{\large 1)} \bf{Vérifier que $\displaystyle{u_{n+1}-3=\frac{4(u_{n}-3)}{2+(3-u_{n})}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$} \\
& \bf{puis montrer par récurrence que $\displaystyle{u_{n}< 3}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.}\\ [0.2cm]
& \textcolor{ao}{\large 2)} \bf{Soit $(v_{n})$ la suite numérique telle que :  $v_{n}=\displaystyle{\frac{u_{n}-1}{3-u_{n}}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.} \\[0.2cm]
0.75 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large a.} \bf{Montrer que $(v_{n})
$ est une suite géométrique de raison $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}$}\\ 
& \hspace{.3in} \bf{puis en déduire que $v_{n}=\displaystyle{\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$.}  \\ [0.2cm] 
0.5 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large b.} \bf{Montrer que $u_{n}=\displaystyle{\frac{1+3v_{n}}{1+v_{n}}}$ pour tout entier naturel $n$ puis écrire $u_{n}$ en fonction de $n$.}\\[0.2cm] 
0.5 & \hspace{.3in}\textcolor{ao(english)}{\large c.} \bf{Déterminer la limite de la suite $\left(u_n\right)$.} \\[0.3cm]
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```